# Building Space using Three.js

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm going to show some planets having twinkle effect or not in one scene using @react-three/fiber in react.js project.
How can I do it?

I've done it using three module but when state is changed in React.js, the scene is re-rendering.